# javascript onclick="return SubmitConfirmation();" of a submit button not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This works in firefox and doesnt work in chrome. The issue looks strange.

I have a submit button as below which calls a javascript function to do some confirmation and prompts based on several checks.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return SubmitConfirmation();" />
```

The java script function is as below

```
  function SubmitConfirmation() {
        showLoading();

        var total = 0;
        $(".table-success").each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($("input[id$='price']", this).val());
        });

        if (total > 50000)
            alert("Please attach details!");

        var _userConfirm = confirm('Do you want to continue?');

        // if the below 'if statement' is not there, everything works as expected.
        if (_userConfirm != true)
            hideLoading();

        return _userConfirm;

    }


    function showLoading()
    {
        $("#divProcessing").show();
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    function hideLoading()
    {
        $("#divProcessing").hide();
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

In mozilla, the above script works without any issues. but in chrome, it wont work if i have the second if check. i cant figure out what is wrong here.

**The function 'SubmitConfirmation' will return a true/false. if true it should submit. In chrome, function is returning true, but the submit is not happening.**

```
if (_userConfirm != true)
//tried to use 
if(!_userConfirm)
```

Im using Chrome, 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit). Any Bug? :s

Comment: define "doesnt work" (and you have a missing quote)

Comment: What does `hideLoading` contain?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Do you see the missing quote in `alert("Please attach details!);`?

Comment: that is a mistake when i pasted the code here. sorry. i will edit it.

Comment: First of all better use `element.addEventListener()`. The `Event.preventDefault()` method tend to bee more reliable than return values like you did.

Comment: Im still not sure what working/not working means - put it this way, given this [mcve] - https://jsfiddle.net/y8d3t5cb/1/ - what is the problem?

Comment: @Jamiec  so basically, this function will return a true/false. if true it should submit. So function is returning true, but the submit is not happening.

Comment: @Bellian, you have any sample? i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this `onclick` of a button - it should be `onsubmit` of the form with no further changes

```
<form onsubmit="return SubmitConfirmation();">
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/y8d3t5cb/2/

Or try the below in both browsers.

```js
function SubmitConfirmation() {
        showLoading();

        var total = 0;
        $(".table-success").each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($("input[id$='price']", this).val());
        });

        if (total > 50000)
            alert("Please attach details!");

        var _userConfirm = confirm('Do you want to continue?');

        // if the below 'if statement' is not there, everything works as expected.
        if (_userConfirm != true)
            hideLoading();
        return _userConfirm;

    }


    function showLoading()
    {
        $("#divProcessing").show();
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    function hideLoading()
    {
        $("#divProcessing").hide();
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

```css
#divProcessing{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return SubmitConfirmation();">
<table class="table-success">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="some_price"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>

<div id="divProcessing">
Processing
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are better of using the `element.addEventListener()` since it is more reliable in most situations https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

```js
document.querySelector('#my-submit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(SubmitConfirmation()){
    return;
  }else{
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
})


function SubmitConfirmation() {
      showLoading();

      var total = 0;
      $(".table-success").each(function () {
          total += parseFloat($("input[id$='price']", this).val());
      });

      if (total > 50000)
          alert("Please attach details!");

      var _userConfirm = confirm('Do you want to continue?');

      // if the below 'if statement' is not there, everything works as expected.
      if (_userConfirm != true)
          hideLoading();

      return _userConfirm;

  }


  function showLoading()
  {
      $("#divProcessing").show();
      $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  function hideLoading()
  {
      $("#divProcessing").hide();
      $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="submit" id="my-submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: dont thi nk you need the `return no()`

Comment: sorry was a tast from before XD

Answer (score -2):

In Chrome, the `confirm` was fired before the `showLoading()` calling. So the trick here is moving your confirm codes into a `setTimeout()` function to break the time.

Btw, you don't need `return` in `onclick="return SubmitConfirmation();"`

```js
function SubmitConfirmation() {
        showLoading();

        var total = 0;
        $(".table-success").each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($("input[id$='price']", this).val());
        });

        if (total > 50000)
            alert("Please attach details!");
        
        setTimeout(function() {
          var _userConfirm = confirm('Do you want to continue?');
          // if the below 'if statement' is not there, everything works as expected.
          if (!_userConfirm) {
            hideLoading();
          }
          return _userConfirm;
        }, 200);

    }

    function showLoading()
    {   
        $("#divProcessing").show();
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    
    function hideLoading()
    {
        $("#divProcessing").hide();
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

```css
#divProcessing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="SubmitConfirmation();" />
<div id="divProcessing">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: this will not prevent a form to be sent in the first place.

Comment: You *absolutely* need the `return`. ALso, returning anything from a `setTimeout` callback is *absolutely pointless*. This answer couldnt be more wrong